# Ask Cortana to Schedule/Start Microsoft Teams Meetings

Tags: microsoft-teams, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I am looking for how can I ask Cortana to perform functionality provided in Microsoft Teams?

e.g.  I should be able to achieve below:

1) Ask Cortana to schedule meeting with Microsoft Teams link on calender

2) Ask Cortana to start/stop Teams meeting

etc.

I have office 365 business Premium subscription, Win 10 (1709) with Cortana setup.

Also, I have read that Cortana is coming Teams and Outlook. However, I am not sure of timeline, release version for the same. Any update on same?

If that is still pending, what is the way I can achieve my above goals like writing cortana custom skill, Teams app  etc???

I am new to Microsoft Teams however, I have automated much of Skype of Business functionality using non-Cortana Voice Assistant. I am switching to Microsoft Teams and want Cortana to performs Teams features.

Any pointers greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can add a bot service bot to teams through chat.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview

You can also interface with teams via Microsoft graph.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/teams_api_overview

And you can wrap it all up in a Cortana skill. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/overview

If you plan on doing this for a big enterprise, Microsoft is current running a Technology Adopters Program for companies wanting to build enterprise skills before February.  You can email cortanae at microsoft for program details ( but you need a committed ship road map to apply. )